# Configuring iOS in app purchases from VS Code

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-code, in-app-purchase

I have been programming my Expo app on visual studio code, and now I am working on in app purchases. I finished programming the cross-platform code and works well on android, however now I need to configurate iOS in app purchases. From what I read, I have to follow some steps on XCode, the problem is that my PC has windows on it. How do I solve the problem and configurate all?

I have a friend which has an iMac, so I could pass him the project and he could configurate the in app purchases. Even if I did this, I would have to syncronize my project with my friend's one, right? Every edit I make in vs code should be uploaded in xcode?